# Change the css of online page and save the css to local computer. Load the local css when You enter the online page

Tags: css, firebug

When i am on online site and i am making changes in local using firebug.

```
p {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

I am trying to save changes i have made in css local file so when i enter the site again the css changes will be loaded from my local pc. When i refresh the page the changes are gone. And i need to edit them again.

Was searching the google but i did nothing about saving the file on local computer and loading it again when entering an online site.

Comment: You can edit the [userContent.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserContent.css) file, or use a utility such as [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/).

Comment: Ok i will check Stylish

Comment: @MrLister You should post your comment as answer, so it can be accepted.